# Dresser Conversion I can't find plans for

Tags: hinges

I can't imagine that someone hasn't built this before, but I can't find anything online resembling what I want to tackle. So I'm coming here for help. Sorry if this is a really basic build and doesn't belong here.

Idea: I want to take a standard 3 drawer dresser and make an open storage compartment to hide a laundry basket with a hinged door made of the disassembled drawer fronts. Here is the plan I have so far:

1. remove the drawer slide components from inside the main compartment of the dresser body
2. detach the face/front of the drawers from the drawers themselves
3. attach all 3 drawer faces to each other as one panel (with some form of reinforcements on the inside)
4. Attach this drawer face panel to the body of the open dresser as a "door." (Like a kitchen cabinet door, but with dresser drawer fronts.)
5. open and close drawer face panel as a door to access laundry.

My questions/things I am nervous about:

1. Do you think this is even possible, or did I just dream this up and it won't work?
2. What type of hinges would I'd need for the door to stay supported from one side? I am worried about the weight of this drawer face "door." The dresser is solid wood, like 50 years old, so the drawer fronts are real wood and heavy.
3. Is this something I could do on my own, with limited skills, but with access to the needed tools?

Thanks in advance! Will try to attach the photo I drew up with my idea.

[image: mydrawing]
[image: openeddresser]
[image: fulldresser]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This isn't too basic for us, no worries there. The reason I suspect you haven't seen any similar projects to what you're hoping to do is that the removal of the internal structures severely compromises the integrity of the carcass. This weakening could be bad enough that the finished project is too unstable to use, unless you take steps to counter the weakening. Do you have the chest of drawers you want to use as the starting point yet? The details of its construction will have to guide what you do (and even whether you should start, it may be too flimsy).

Comment: Don't worry about the hinges BTW, it's not trivial to hang a heavy-ish door, but two hinges should have zero problem with the final weight. What you'll end end up with will not be heavier than many workshop cabinet doors (which have tools hung from them) and further than that, a lot of older houses had room doors hung from only 2 hinges.

Comment: One last thing I just thought of, another thing that may not be easy is removing the fronts from the drawers, again depending on how they are put together. There are a number of construction methods (including dovetails) that may mean sawing them off is the only viable method.

Comment: Thank you Graphus for your notes, appreciate the brainstorming!
   I was thinking about the stability of the structure also. To recycle what I have, I was thinking I could re-use the existing drawer support beams to reinforce the back of the dresser. Maybe crisscross them along the back from each side, add a few more if needed too? I don't anticipate the inside looking pretty, just supportive.

Comment: For removing the drawer fronts I was planning on using a little handheld jig-saw that I have and cut them off that way. Then use my electric sander to smooth any jagged edges.
And thanks for the confirmation on the hinges. That is true, doors can weigh a lot so this shouldn't be much different. To answer your earlier question, yes I have the dresser already. It is really sturdy, and was built a long time ago, its been in my family for a long time.

Comment: If the carcass is built strongly enough, as older stuff is more likely to be than almost all modern furniture, this might work (might) but they do still rely on the front bracing structures for part of their structural integrity. I think we'd all want to see photos of the interior and rear so we can get an idea for ourselves. If it's not then a replacement back of beefy plywood — 1/2" or better for confidence — firmly attached would probably remove racking worries (as it can for example on a bookcase that has floating shelves).

Comment: But quite honestly, if I were you and I had access to a jigsaw and a few other key tools, plus had a local plywood source that stocked hardwood ply (not cheaper softwood plywood) I would just build this from scratch and save the chest of drawers. Building from scratch has a lot of advantages, not the least of them being a much simpler door construction.

Comment: Pictures of the actual dresser with the drawers removed would help us get a better idea of what you're facing. Another advantage of building a new dresser from scratch is that you get to keep the old one. Old often means sentimental. It also (usually) means better quality wood & construction. If the old one isn't sentimental, you may make enough selling it to notably offset the cost of material for making a new one from scratch.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comments! Sorry for the delay, the week got away from me. Attached are photos of the dresser. Hope that helps with visualization.

Comment: An idea I had to make it more stable, once the insides are removed, is to add a false floor. As in -- I take a piece of plywood and attach the chunk from the bottom, which would prevent the sides of the dresser from bowing open in the front with the weight of the door. Thoughts? 
The idea of keeping this as is, and building from scratch, seems more intimidating to me than repurposing honestly. And I don't really have reason/or a place for this one in its designed function. Changing it to this hidden-laundry-compartment would tidy up my existing space and not take up anymore room.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought of building your own "drawer fronts"? You could use one solid sheet of plywood and smaller sheets to create the look of drawers and molding to trim it out.[image: this is just an example]

Comment: I don't understand how the picture you show is made out of sheet goods.

Comment: This appears to be a simple restatement of what the OP _wants_ to do, and doesn't really provide information on the _how_, which is what the OP is after.